# What is this GCC error on Linux, and how do I solve it? gcc: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction (program as)

Tags: c, gcc, raspbian, gcc4.6

I type `gcc hello.c` and this appears:

```
gcc: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction (program as)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

hello.c is just:

```
int main()
{
 return 0;
}
```

I can't think of any way to make it simpler! (The same happened with `printf` in there.)

So: how do you fix this? I'm on Raspian, on Raspberry Pi.

#### Edit

gcc -v gives

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
```

No I didn't install it.

As for updates, `sudo apt-get install gcc` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Yes, you can run `as`, it says `Illegal instruction` with no arguments.

I have no idea what swap space is.

`gcc -O0 -g hello.c` gives the same error.

gcc does not recognise `--enable-debug`.

Comment: add your version of gcc.

Comment: Looks like it is gcc-4.6

Comment: Do you have swap space configured?

Comment: @maverik "gcc -v" tells us much more, including what target it was configured for. Maybe it's emitting instructions for one architecture and `as` is configured for a different one?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45363

Comment: Did you install the compiler by yourself?

Comment: I agree with Graham. Looks like your gcc build is misconfigured.

Comment: @GrahamLee: I think it is supposed to be "program __was__" not "program __as__", it will spit out the program. Or sometimes the program name is `as` such as `./as` or assembler.

Comment: Either your installation is broken in some way, or there's a huge gaping bug in gcc assembler (`as`) for Raspian. Can you run `as` from the command line?

Comment: @0a0d: the program is called `as`, as in `as`sembler. It's a part of gcc.

Comment: @n.m.: Yep, that's what I wrote

Comment: `as` is part of binutils, not gcc.

Comment: Thanks guys. No luck so far, but I've tried the stuff.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to others with the same problem. I put the error message in the title.

Comment: @raymond Good idea: I'll try to remember that in my next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! I uninstalled gcc, installed gcc-4.7, and ... nothing.

I cleared out the end of gcc-4.6 and re-ran `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7` and ... nothing.

I updated binutils and ... it worked!

So, `as` didn't appear to be affected by updating GCC, but updating it more directly did it for me.

*(It was from 2.22-7.1 to 2.22-8, if that helps anyone.)*

Comment: Urgh: I really should have mentioned that: "as" is part of binutils and not gcc...

Answer (score 2):

I can only shed some light on the error message:

> gcc: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction (program as)

gcc does several things when compiling. It first translates your C program into assembler and then converts the assembler into machine code.

The name of the assembler program with gcc is just `as`. So the error message tells you, that running the assembler fails, because the assembler executable contains an illegal instruction.

This might really be an hardware error, meaning that the executable of the assembler is broken.

To check:

1. Does `gcc -S hello.c` work ? That should create a "hello.s" containing the C code compiled to assembler
2. You might try with `gcc -v -c hello.c` to find out what happens exactly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `gcc -S hello.c` works well, and `gcc -v -c hello.c` appears to show that the error occurs when running `as -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -meabi=5 -o hello.o /tmp/ccw3B7UV.s`. If I run that on its own it prints ... `Illegal instruction`.

Answer (score 1):

Found on raspberryPi forums:

> Grabbed the sources and tried a cross-compile on an x86-64 box for a generic arm target. Something inside filter/hq2x.cpp is causing GCC to go nuts and consume memory & swap, so I wouldn't be at all surprised if it triggers a fatal error on a Pi. Some sources suggest that it is the compiler's (cc1plus) internal stack overflowing.
>
> One possible fix is to run the configure script with --enable-debug - This should reduce optimization to a minimum and avoid stack overflows at the expense of increased binary size.

So you can try to set compiler flags to

```
-O0 -g
```

and check whether it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Got similar problem.

But it happened after move of VirtualBox image (with Xubuntu 16.04/gcc-5) from Haswell based machine to Sandy Bridge. Problem was somewhere in build-essential / gcc / binutils packages. I reinstalled all of them (with apt remove and apt install - no oneshot reinstall) - it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the compiler and try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

That might solve the problem.