# Error build exmaple with WICED SDK

Tags: gcc-warning

I compile an example in WICED SDK 3.5.2 by command:
./make snip.scan-BCM943362WCD4
And it shows this error:

```
MAKEFILE MAKECMDGOALS=snip.scan-BCM943362WCD4 OTA2_SUPPORT is disabled
Building Bootloader
WICED/platform/GCC/math_newlib.c: In function 'sin':
WICED/platform/GCC/math_newlib.c:30:5: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
     x -= ( (int) ( x / ( 2 * PI ) ) ) * 2 * PI;
     ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
make[3]: *** [build/waf.bootloader-NoOS-BCM943362WCD4/Modules/WICED/platform/GCC/math_newlib.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [main_app] Error 2
make[1]: *** [bootloader] Error 2
make: *** [main_app] Error 2
```

what should i try to fix it? thks

Comment: mabye this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526493/what-is-this-gcc-error-on-linux-and-how-do-i-solve-it-gcc-internal-compiler-e

Comment: try updating gcc, if that doesn't work just follow the instructions presumably.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on a 64-bit Linux system. It means that "as" or some other tool in the bundled GNU toolchain encounters an illegal instruction.

So they've been built for a newer host CPU than the one you happen to have. I managed to get around it by moving tools/ARM_GNU/bin/Linux64 out of the way, then creating a symlink from Linux64 to Linux32.